# Odata POST create entity with additional parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, post, asp.net-web-api, odata

I implemented an odata controller that creates an entity on a POST request.

```
public virtual IHttpActionResult Post(TEntity e)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _service.Insert(e);

    return Created(e);
}
```

I want to create a successor/copy of an existing entity. So I load the existing entity via `GET`, strip out some data (e.g. the ID) show it in my UI and send it via `POST`. But I want to copy some additional objects / do some more stuff if the entity is a successor.

Do I have to use an odata action or can I pass additional parameters like `POST: odata/Entity?successorOf=12345`? How can I read this parameters? Or is there a better odata-way of doing this?